# Can the band gap of quantum dots (QDs) be determined just by knowing the Bohr radius and the size of the QDs?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photon-emission, nanoscience

After extensive research, I've discovered that accurately determining the emission wavelength of quantum dots (QDs) requires understanding several key factors. As highlighted in the book "***Introduction to Nanoscience and Nanomaterials***," ([here](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789814397988_0004)) two crucial elements are the energy gap of the bulk material and the reduced mass of the exciton. These parameters are essential for calculating the energy gap of QDs. However, the problem at hand only provides the Bohr radius and the size of the QDs. With just these details, predicting the color of light emission becomes a challenge, as the information is incomplete for a precise calculation.

[image]

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.